# SwiftUI: Wedge shape with inner stroke

Tags: drawing, border, shapes, swiftui

I’m trying to make a chart like the one pictured.

[image]

The code below is fine, but I'd really like the border of each wedge drawn with an inner stroke (instead of centered):

```
import SwiftUI

struct WedgeShape: Shape {
    var startAngle: Angle
    var endAngle: Angle

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()

        p.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width/2, y: rect.size.width/2),
            radius: rect.size.width/2,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: false
        )

        return p
    }
}

struct Wedge {
    var startAngle: Double
    var endAngle: Double
    var color: Color
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var wedges = [
        Wedge(startAngle: 0, endAngle: 90, color: Color.red),
        Wedge(startAngle: 90, endAngle: 180, color: Color.green),
        Wedge(startAngle: 180, endAngle: 360, color: Color.blue)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< wedges.count) {
                WedgeShape(
                    startAngle: Angle(degrees: self.wedges[$0].startAngle),
                    endAngle: Angle(degrees: self.wedges[$0].endAngle)
                )
                .stroke(self.wedges[$0].color, lineWidth: 44)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I could simply adjust the view's frame to account the stroke. However, I want something like `Circle().strokeBorder(Color.green, lineWidth: 44)` where the stroke is already accounted for. The `InsettableShape` protocol looks like it could be helpful for this, but I'm not sure how to use the `inset(by:)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I created my wedge shape. I drew the full path of the wedge, and then you can set the `foregroundColor`. Just change `a0` and `a1` to change the length of the wedge.

```swift
struct WedgeShape: Shape {
  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var p = Path()
    let a0 = Angle(degrees: 0.0)
    let a1 = Angle(degrees: 270.0)
    let cen =  CGPoint(x: rect.size.width/2, y: rect.size.width/2)
    let r0 = rect.size.width/3.5
    let r1 = rect.size.width/2
    p.addArc(center: cen, radius: r0, startAngle: a0, endAngle: a1, clockwise: false)
    p.addArc(center: cen, radius: r1, startAngle: a1, endAngle: a0, clockwise: true)
    p.closeSubpath()
    return p
  }
}

// Then in your `View`
var body: some View {
    WedgeShape()
      .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
      .foregroundColor(.green)
}
```

Comment: Nice! I hadn't thought about using 2 arcs.

Answer (score 3):

With help of `strokedPath()`, it's enought to adjust `rect` like here:

```swift
struct Ring: Shape {

    var progress: Double = 0.0
    var thickness: Double = 10.0

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        let halfThickness = CGFloat(thickness / 2.0)
        let rect = rect.insetBy(dx: halfThickness, dy: halfThickness)

        return Path() {
            $0.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY),
                      radius: min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2,
                      startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90),
                      endAngle: Angle(degrees: -90 + 360 * progress),
                      clockwise: false)
        }.strokedPath(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: CGFloat(thickness), lineCap: .round))
    }

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { progress }
        set { progress = min(1.0, max(0, newValue)) }
    }
}
```

then just

```swift
Ring(progress: 0.5).foregroundColor(.red)
```

Comment: Good point! Admittedly, using `progress` might be easier for the caller too. The caveat with this answer is that in order to achieve the image from my question, data needs to be sorted in descending order (to prevent larger values from covering smaller ones). Rotation may be required depending on what you're after too.

Comment: To clarify, I meant the caveat with using `progress` instead of start and end angles. Using `strokedPath` is certainly a simpler implementation than 2 arcs :)

Comment: Sure, so my goal was not to provide you with ready `Wedge` implementation, but rather show how to draw stroked arc without exceeding `Shape` boundaries. Personally I prefer above technique, since it's simpler than 2 arcs.

Regarding `progress`, just left it here so the example compiles, but I believe it's unrelated to your answer.

Comment: While this doesn't seem to be the answer to the question, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution based on Ricky Padilla's answer that refactors `WedgeShape` to take a `startAngle`, `endAngle` and `lineWidth` at the call site.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WedgeShape: Shape {
    let startAngle: Angle
    let endAngle: Angle
    let lineWidth: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()
        let center =  CGPoint(x: rect.size.width/2, y: rect.size.width/2)
        let r1 = rect.size.width/2
        p.addArc(center: center, radius: abs(lineWidth - r1), startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false)
        p.addArc(center: center, radius: r1, startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: true)
        p.closeSubpath()
        return p
    }
}

struct Wedge {
    var startAngle: Double
    var endAngle: Double
    var color: Color
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let wedges = [
        Wedge(startAngle: -45, endAngle: 45, color: Color.blue),
        Wedge(startAngle: 45, endAngle: 180, color: Color.green),
        Wedge(startAngle: 180, endAngle: -45, color: Color.red)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< wedges.count) {
                WedgeShape(
                    startAngle: Angle(degrees: self.wedges[$0].startAngle),
                    endAngle: Angle(degrees: self.wedges[$0].endAngle),
                    lineWidth: 44
                )
                .foregroundColor(self.wedges[$0].color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, an alternative option using average Joe's answer:

```
import SwiftUI

struct WedgeShape: Shape {
    var progress: Double
    var lineWidth: CGFloat
    var lineCap: CGLineCap = .butt

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let insetWidth = lineWidth/2
        let rect = rect.insetBy(dx: insetWidth, dy: insetWidth)

        return Path() {
            $0.addArc(
                center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY),
                radius: min(rect.width, rect.height)/2,
                startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90),
                endAngle: Angle(degrees: -90 + 360 * progress),
                clockwise: false
            )
        }
        .strokedPath(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: lineCap))
    }
}

struct Wedge {
    var progress: Double
    var color: Color
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let wedges = [
        Wedge(progress: 1, color: Color.green),
        Wedge(progress: 0.625, color: Color.blue),
        Wedge(progress: 0.375, color: Color.red)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< wedges.count) {
                WedgeShape(
                    progress: self.wedges[$0].progress,
                    lineWidth: 44
                )
                .foregroundColor(self.wedges[$0].color)
            }
        }
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody I cannot name asked me to leave this code here. He noticed it's safe to run and will not steal your crypto. Based on Ricky Padilla's and JWK's examples.

```
struct WedgeShape: Shape {
    let startAngle: Angle
    let endAngle: Angle
    let outterScale: CGFloat
    let innerScale: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()
        let center =  CGPoint(x: rect.size.width/2, y: rect.size.width/2)
        //let r1 = rect.size.width/2
        p.addArc(center: center,
                 radius: outterScale*rect.size.width/2,
                 //radius: abs(lineWidth - r1),
                 startAngle: startAngle,
                 endAngle: endAngle,
                 clockwise: false)
        p.addArc(center: center,
                 //radius: abs(lineWidth - r1),
                 radius: innerScale*rect.size.width/6,
                 startAngle: endAngle,
                 endAngle: startAngle,
                 clockwise: true)
        p.closeSubpath()
        return p
    }
}

struct Wedge {
    var startAngle: Double
    var endAngle: Double
    var color: Color
}

struct ContentViewWedge: View {
    let pokemonWedges = [
        //Wedge(startAngle: -45, endAngle: 45, color: Color.blue),
        Wedge(startAngle: 90, endAngle: 270, color: Color.white),
        Wedge(startAngle: -90, endAngle: 90, color: Color.red)
    ]

    let backgroundWedge = Wedge(startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, color: Color.black)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            WedgeShape(startAngle: Angle(degrees: self.backgroundWedge.startAngle-90),
                       endAngle: Angle(degrees: self.backgroundWedge.endAngle-90),
                       outterScale: 1.07,
                       innerScale: 1)
                .foregroundColor(self.backgroundWedge.color)
            WedgeShape(
                startAngle: Angle(degrees: self.pokemonWedges[1].startAngle-90),
                endAngle: Angle(degrees: self.pokemonWedges[1].endAngle-90),
                outterScale: 1,
                innerScale: 1.3
            ).foregroundColor(self.pokemonWedges[1].color).offset(y: -3)
            WedgeShape(
             startAngle: Angle(degrees: self.pokemonWedges[0].startAngle-90),
             endAngle: Angle(degrees: self.pokemonWedges[0].endAngle-90),
             outterScale: 1,
             innerScale: 1.3
             ).foregroundColor(self.pokemonWedges[0].color).offset(y: +3)
        }
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .padding(20)
    }
}

struct WedgeShapeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentViewWedge()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Circle shapes with trim

```
struct WedgeView: View {
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 60

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: 0.4)
                .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .butt)
            ).rotationEffect(.degrees(-180))
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: 0.2)
                .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .butt)
            ).rotationEffect(.degrees(-180 + 360.0 * 0.4))
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: 0.4)
                .stroke(Color.green, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .butt)
            ).rotationEffect(.degrees(-180.0 + 360.0 * 0.6)) // 0.6 = 0.4 + 0.2

        }
             // Stroke draws over the edge, so we add some padding to keep things within the frame
            .padding(lineWidth/2)
    }
}
```

Everything is hardcoded here but you get the gist of it.